# How to add the multiple existing virtual networks and subnets in storage account ARM template using iterator concept?

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-rm-template, azure-virtual-network, subnet

I have created the Azure Storage Account by adding the existing virtual networks using the following ARM template.

```
    {
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "storageAccountName": {
            "type": "string",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "Specifies the name of the Azure Storage account."
            }
        },
        "storageAccountType": {
            "type": "string",
            "defaultValue": "Standard_LRS",
            "allowedValues": [
                "Standard_LRS",
                "Standard_GRS",
                "Standard_RAGRS",
                "Standard_ZRS",
                "Premium_LRS"
            ],
            "metadata": {
                "description": "Storage Account type."
            }
        },
        "storageAccessTier": {
            "type": "string",
            "defaultValue": "Hot",
            "allowedValues": [
                "Hot",
                "Cool"
            ],
            "metadata": {
                "description": "Set the access tier of the Storage Account."
            }
        },
        "storageKind": {
            "type": "string",
            "defaultValue": "StorageV2",
            "allowedValues": [
                "StorageV2",
                "Storage"
            ],
            "metadata": {
                "description": "Set the storage kind of the Storage Account."
            }
        },
        "storageAccounthttpsTrafficOnlyEnabled": {
            "type": "bool",
            "defaultValue": true,
            "metadata": {
                "description": "Enable or disable enforcing HTTPS only access."
            }
        },
        "allowBlobPublicAccess": {
            "type": "bool",
            "defaultValue": false,
            "metadata": {
                "description": "Enable or disable blob public access"
            }
        },
        "isHnsEnabled": {
            "type": "bool",
            "defaultValue": true,
            "metadata": {
                "description": "Enable or disable ADLS Gen2 hierarchical namespace"
            }
        },
        "containerNames": {
            "type": "array",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "The container names"
            }
        },
        "location": {
            "type": "string",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "Specifies the location in which the Azure Storage resources should be deployed."
            }
        },
        "environment": {
            "type": "string",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "Specify the environment name"
            }
        },
        "subscriptionOwner": {
            "type": "string",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "Specify the email address of the subscription owner"
            }
        },
        "vnetResourceGroupName": {
            "type": "string",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "The name of the existing resource group which contains the virtual network"
            }
        },
        "vnetName": {
            "type": "string",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "The name of the existing virtual network"
            }
        },
        "subnet01Name": {
            "type": "string",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "The name of the db subnet"
            }
        },
        "subnet02Name": {
            "type": "string",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "The name of the default subnet"
            }
        },
        "subnet03Name": {
            "type": "string",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "The name of the ise1 subnet"
            }
        },
        "subnet04Name": {
            "type": "string",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "The name of the ise2 subnet"
            }
        },
        "subnet05Name": {
            "type": "string",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "The name of the ise3 subnet"
            }
        },
        "subnet06Name": {
            "type": "string",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "The name of the ise4 subnet"
            }
        },
        "subnet07Name": {
            "type": "string",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "The name of the tools subnet"
            }
        }
    },
    "variables": {
        "vnetResourceId": "[resourceId(parameters('vnetResourceGroupName'),'Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks',parameters('vnetName'))]"
    },
    "resources": [
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts",
            "apiVersion": "2020-08-01-preview",
            "name": "[parameters('storageAccountName')]",
            "location": "[parameters('location')]",
            "sku": {
                "name": "[parameters('storageAccountType')]",
                "tier": "Standard"
            },
            "kind": "[parameters('storageKind')]",
            "properties": {
                "accessTier": "[parameters('storageAccessTier')]",
                "allowBlobPublicAccess": "[parameters('allowBlobPublicAccess')]",
                "isHnsEnabled": "[parameters('isHnsEnabled')]",
                "supportsHttpsTrafficOnly": "[parameters('storageAccounthttpsTrafficOnlyEnabled')]",
                "networkAcls": {
                    "resourceAccessRules": [
                    ],
                    "bypass": "AzureServices",
                    "virtualNetworkRules": [
                        {
                            "id": "[concat(variables('vnetResourceId'), '/subnets/',parameters('subnet01Name'))]",
                            "action": "Allow",
                            "state": "Succeeded"
                        },
                        {
                            "id": "[concat(variables('vnetResourceId'), '/subnets/',parameters('subnet02Name'))]",
                            "action": "Allow",
                            "state": "Succeeded"
                        },
                        {
                            "id": "[concat(variables('vnetResourceId'), '/subnets/',parameters('subnet03Name'))]",
                            "action": "Allow",
                            "state": "Succeeded"
                        },
                        {
                            "id": "[concat(variables('vnetResourceId'), '/subnets/',parameters('subnet04Name'))]",
                            "action": "Allow",
                            "state": "Succeeded"
                        },
                        {
                            "id": "[concat(variables('vnetResourceId'), '/subnets/',parameters('subnet05Name'))]",
                            "action": "Allow",
                            "state": "Succeeded"
                        },
                        {
                            "id": "[concat(variables('vnetResourceId'), '/subnets/',parameters('subnet06Name'))]",
                            "action": "Allow",
                            "state": "Succeeded"
                        },
                        {
                            "id": "[concat(variables('vnetResourceId'), '/subnets/',parameters('subnet07Name'))]",
                            "action": "Allow",
                            "state": "Succeeded"
                        }
                    ],
                    "ipRules": [
                        {
                            "value": "xxxxxxxx",
                            "action": "Allow"
                        }
                    ],
                    "defaultAction": "Deny"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/blobServices/containers",
            "apiVersion": "2020-08-01-preview",
            "name": "[concat(parameters('storageAccountName'),'/default/', parameters('containerNames')[copyIndex()])]",
            "copy": {
                "name": "containercopy",
                "count": "[length(parameters('containerNames'))]"
            },
            "dependsOn": [
                "[resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', parameters('storageAccountName'))]"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "outputs": {
        "storageAccountName": {
            "type": "string",
            "value": "[parameters('storageAccountName')]"
        },
        "containerNames": {
            "type": "array",
            "value": "[parameters('containerNames')]"
        }
    }
   }
```

In the above template, I have used multiple parameters to provide the virtual networks and subnets. But I want to use the copy operator for adding the existing virtual networks and subnets.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an approach that I've taken.

```
  "parameters": {
    ...
    "ipRules": {
      "type": "array"
    },
    "virtualNetworkSubnetsIds": {
      "type": "array"
    }
  },
  "variables": {
    "copy": [
      {
        "name": "ipRules",
        "count": "[length(parameters('ipRules'))]",
        "input": {
          "value": "[parameters('ipRules')[copyIndex('ipRules')]]"
        }
      },
      {
        "name": "virtualNetworkRules",
        "count": "[length(parameters('virtualNetworkSubnetsIds'))]",
        "input": {
          "id": "[parameters('virtualNetworkSubnetsIds')[copyIndex('virtualNetworkRules')]]",
          "action": "Allow",
          "ignoreMissingVNetServiceEndpoint": false
        }
      }
    ]
  },
```

In the storage account deployment, I assign the variables to the properties.

```
        "networkAcls": {
          "defaultAction": "Deny",
          "bypass": "AzureServices",
          "ipRules": "[variables('ipRules')]",
          "virtualNetworkRules": "[variables('virtualNetworkRules')]"
        },
```

Comment: Thanks @Stringfellow, I don't want to create the array type parameter for `virtualNetworkSubnetsIds`. I want to create the array type parameters for virtual networks and subnets and then get the subnet resourceid and assign it to the `virtualNetworkRules`